# EditText Cursor Positioning Inaccuracies

Tags: android, debugging, android-edittext, android-screen-support

I'e been experiencing some odd behavior from the text cursor in the `EditText`s of my android application. Essentially, the cursor does not always accurately represent it's position in a word (**it's all over the place**). As such, typing a character into an edit text can result in the character being placed somewhere different (**usually before or after the cursor indicated position**). Also, when the cursor is placed inside of or next to a word, that word is often offset slightly.

Here is an example of the phenomenon;

[image]

Notice the words moving position from picture to picture, and in the second example the cursor indicates that it is before the `i` but is in fact before the `e` two indexes to the right.

Here is the `EditText` element of this `View` in the XML;

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/hazard_obs_text"              
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hazard_observation"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hazard_observation"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hazard_observation"
    android:layout_above="@+id/finalise_hazard"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"        
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:hint="Recommendation Text"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:enabled="false"
/>
```

As you can see, it is inside a `RelativeLayout`, and has a custom blank white background with some subtle shading around the edge. It is also part of a `Fragment` layout. Nothing out of the ordinary as far as I can see. No exceptions or errors are being thrown. I am stumped. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this odd behavior?

### **Extra details by request;**

The Layout isn't changed programmatically in any way except to be inflated initially (it is in a Fragment after all). Below is any line of code that interacts programmatically with the above example `EditText` -

```
obsText = (EditText) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.hazard_obs_text);
...
obsText.setEnabled(tf); // Where tf is a boolean value.
...
obsText.getText().clear();
...   
obsText.setText(observations[0].split(" ­ ", 3)[1]); // Where observations[0] is a string.
...
obsText.setText(currentAssessment.obsDescript); // Setting another string.
```

Below is the full fragment layout. It is worth noting that I am also having the same issue in a very simple LinearLayout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="#070054"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"           
            >
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/hazard_code"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hazard_code_browse_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="Hazard Code"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent"
    android:dropDownHeight="125dp"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="1dp"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/hazard_code_browse_button"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"      
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sfrp_drops"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/crossselector"        
/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/hazard_observation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sfrp_drops"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pictures"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownHeight="125dp"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="1dp"
    android:enabled="false"     
/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sfrp_drops"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"               
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
> 
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/hazard_severity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"                      
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
        android:prompt="@string/hazard_severity"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:enabled="false"
    />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/hazard_frequency"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
        android:prompt="@string/hazard_frequency"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:enabled="false"
    />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/hazard_risk"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
        android:prompt="@string/hazard_risk"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:enabled="false"
    />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/hazard_priority"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
        android:prompt="@string/hazard_priority"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:enabled="false"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pictures"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/photoreel"        
> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/hal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   
        android:layout_weight="1"    
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/hazard_obs_text"              
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hazard_observation"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hazard_observation"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hazard_observation"
    android:layout_above="@+id/finalise_hazard"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"        
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:hint="Recommendation Text"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:enabled="false"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/hazard_act_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sfrp_drops"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sfrp_drops"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sfrp_drops"
    android:layout_above="@+id/finalise_hazard"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:hint="Observation Text"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:enabled="false"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/finalise_hazard"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"      
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hazard_obs_text"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hazard_act_text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/plainbuttonselector"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Finalise Entry"
    android:enabled="false"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/peoples_at_risk"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hazard_location"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hazard_code"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hazard_act_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:hint="Peoples at Risk"
    android:enabled="false"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/hazard_location"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hazard_code"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hazard_code"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hazard_act_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="Hazard Location"
    android:enabled="false"
/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/relevant_legistlation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/peoples_at_risk"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hazard_code"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hazard_act_text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebackselector"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="Relevant Legislation"
    android:enabled="false"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am experiencing the issue on a Nexus 10, Galaxy Note 10.1, & Xperia Z2 tablets with the latest version of Android installed. I've also tested this on an old Xperia phone as well which is not having the issue, which begs the question of whether it could be related to screen size. Other applications on the same devices aren't having this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This has been hounding me for some time now. I am willing to manually award a bounty to anyone who can help towards a solution/explanation.

Comment: I've since tested changes to most of the attributes in the EditText to no avail. Textsize, gravity, padding, background and the height and width of the View don't affect it. I've also tested to see whether the fact that the elements size is dynamically determined had anything to do with it (using fixed sizes does nothing to help).

Comment: Did you see if this can be a problem with your adapter.. Rather than edittext?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am willing to give a bounty of 100 to anyone who can offer any helpful insights (even after the original bounty on the question runs out). Seems it is happening marginally in other places in the same app but I can't find any common denominators.

Comment: Any reason why `layout_width` and `layout_height` are set to 0? Anyway the problem might not be directly related to the `EditText` itself. It  could be something else in the layout which is causing this. Could you please post more of your layout? And do you programmatically edit the layout? If yes please post that code too. Any code that has something to do with the UI would be helpful. I guess what I'm asking is if you do something unusual in code which might make an `EditText` behave this way? Also have you tested this on other devices? The device itself might just be the problem.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - The width and height are set to 0 because the actual width and height are determined by the Views around it (good practice in a RelativeLayout), but the same is happening with an EditText which has it's height and width explicitly declared. I've posted up a greater proportion of the relevant code. I am setting the EditText's content, but then even if I test it without setting the content, any text I put in manually while the app is running suffers the same issues.

Comment: I will take a look at the layout and will try to reproduce the problem. On a first glance the only thing I noticed was that you are using `fill_parent` as `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the layout. `fill_parent` is actually deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. I don't think that this causes the error, but it should be corrected nevertheless. Use `match_parent` it does the exact same thing as `fill_parent` with the bonus of the name actually describing how it behaves. `fill_parent` can be a bit misleading and I think that is the reason why it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a great deal of time trying various bits'n'bobs to solve this issue, but the final change that fixed it entirely was adding a (previously absent) `uses-sdk` element and it's attributes to the Android Manifest.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

These were the lowest values that could be declared without incurring the problem.

---

Comment: Before trying the above, something which reduced the issue was adding support for Extra large screens using the `supports-screens` element in the Android Manifest and then manually creating layouts to put in a `layout-xlarge` folder rather than relying on compatibility mode.

    `<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>`